# Filter Questions and/or Answers That Contain Code?

Tags: feature-request

Is it possible to search/filter questions containing code or that have answers containing code?

Answer (score 1):

No it is not.

You could probably search based on some keywords within certain programming languages. But a perfect search for only questions/answers that contain code will be close to impossible.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Ólafur's response, even if you could, you would find that a very large number of questions and answers contain code.  And of those that don't, they may still contain code blocks used for formatting.

By contrast, if you need coding help, such a filter might omit the result you need merely because someone describes the procedure in prose rather than in a code block.

So, why would you need such a search?

Comment: I find reading code to be beneficial.

Comment: @GoogleUser: Me too.  Also, waffles.

Comment: @Adam: How do you read a waffle?

Comment: Same as you read braille.

Comment: @gnovice: you read the burn pattern before you eat it.

Comment: @gnovice: You need the backside of the Rosetta Stone.

Comment: StackOverflow dev days need to serve waffles. On a stick with butter and syrup dipping sauce.

Comment: @Ólafur: But then a waffle would just be a bunch of whitespace (i.e. no *raised* dots).

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://statoverflow.com/sandbox.  Query for posts with `<code>` in the body of the question and at least one joined answer. Note that the site is using data that's couple months out of date now, though.

Comment: So how do I search for code examples on that? ;)

Comment: The big box takes direct sql queries.

Comment: "Hey, I know SQL!" (Jurasic Park takoff).